# Can Visual Studio 2010 C++ inherit include path from referenced projects?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

Visual Studio C++'s project reference (Accessible in *Property Pages/Common Properties/Add New Reference...*) feature allows you to use the symbol definitions in one project (e.g. project A a static lib) in another (e.g. project B an executable).

Adding a reference 'automates' adding project A's output directory into project B's *Property Pages/Linker/General/Additional Library Dependencies*, and adding the name of A's output lib into project B's *Property Pages/Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies*.

Q: Is there a way to make project B automatically include the include path from project A, e.g. through a macro in project B's *Property Pages/C,C++/General/Additional Include Directories*?

Thankyou.

Comment: There is no automatic way to do it. Using macros will let you enter a path relative to the project/solution directory instead of an absolute path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [Property Sheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correct, then you had a similar problem as me. You can find an  answer to this related problem here: [Get Include Directories for custom build step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610538/get-include-directories-for-custom-build-step)